# How to assign a module in Menu [Joomla 2.5]

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am using  Module **JLV FACEBOOK LOGIN** and i want to assign this module as a Menu item in template.

1. Why i cant see the **JLV FACEBOOK LOGIN**   module in the following screenshots
   [image]

I know i am asking the same question which people had already asked but i am new to joomla  ,so please bear my mistake. Any Suggested tutorial or any link to how do use module as a menu will   be really helpful for me 
Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast forwarding to the output of this `JLV FACEBOOK LOGIN menu Item`. 
So, once you click on this link, it should take you to the module displayed on its own page?

If you are affirmative on this, then, you just need to insert the module to an article and link the article to the menu.

And if this is not what you intended from the menu link, then what is the expected output when the menu item is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

To assign module to a menu, you cannot use menu manager. Go to extensions -> module manager, open your JLV FACEBOOK LOGIN module, set in options for which menu items it should be enabled and in which template position, and publish the module.

Note that you cannot add Module as a menu link, that is possible only with Components. Module is an extension which is supposed to be just a small part of a page, it cannot be page of it's own, like Component

Comment: @-marko D ,is there any way to convert Module into Components?

Comment: They are very different, but why not. Read tutorial about creating Joomla components - http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Comment: @-Marko - is there any way to include the module into existing component?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks  all for helping me out.
So finally I have included the **Module** in **Article** with the help of plugin [Load module into Article.](http://www.pages-and-items.com/extensions/load-module-into-article) and then included the Article in **Menu**.

Hope this will help some Newbie like me

Comment: You could also have used the core {loadmodule} or {loadposition} facility.